# Jquery mobile button and textbox issue when focus on Android

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

im running on Android 4.2.2 and facing display issues when i tap on button or typing in the textbox.

Button move when tap ([see here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1o4hhrb1f9u3bt/menu.png))
Text overflow when typing ([see here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/684cfjujb05m0st/textbox.png))

The content seems to drop and leave transparent spaces. I did not overwrite jquery mobile default css and does not have any other js running on them! Just pure HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

for input

```
<input type="text">
```

you can use css to avoid overwrite

```
input {-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;}
```

Comment: It is just normal html coding. 

<input id="loginUser" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" />

10% of the time, it is working fine, 90% have the issue. I wondering if it is the jquery mobile js file or css file have problem loading...